# Delete with select in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 columns(id,parent,value) with some data and this query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = (
    SELECT parent FROM test WHERE id=2 AND value='value' LIMIT 1
);
```

The query above works great.

Now how can I delete instead of select that id in one query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot delete from a table and select from that same table in a subselect.

You can however use that table in a self-join.

```
DELETE t1 FROM test t1
INNER JOIN test t2 ON (t1.id = t2.parent)
WHERE t2.id = 2 and t2.value = 'value'
```

You cannot use `limit` not `order by` in a joined delete statement.
It's either the join or the limit/order by, take your pick.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

Comment: What if the child gets deleted first?

Comment: @Justin, this will only delete items in t1. MySQL will use a temporary table if needed to hold the values in the joined resultset.

Comment: I don't get it. From where did you get t1 and t2? I have one table test.

Comment: @Alqin, he instantiated `t1` and `t2` to differentiate between the table from which he is deleting and the table to which he is joining.

Comment: @Johan please take a second look at syntax. I does not work with LIMIT 1 at the end.

Comment: Thanks... I like this solution, It's simple and allows to have multiple columns in the where clause.

Answer (score 5):

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE id = ( select * from (
    SELECT parent FROM test WHERE id=2 AND value='value' LIMIT 1 ) as t
)
```

Comment: This actually works! My first impression was that won't work but it does. Tanks!

Comment: @Nick, Yes I have and besides, the text in the comment is a literal quote from the link provided.

Comment: Wow, are there badges for having a downvoted answer accepted? So, I don't understand: was the table cached because it was given an alias?

Comment: @Justin, nick is tricking the query optimizer. It doesn't know it selecting from and deleting from the same table. Because he's nesting the table 2 levels deep. The query optimizer doesn't test for that.